# WordPress Fatal Error: call to undefined function

Tags: wordpress

Hey All, 
I'm a bit new to the WordPress game, and was trying to set up my server with WordPress. I was running through the installation, and just entered the host, db name, and pass, and hit go, when I see this:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_admin() in /var/www/WordPress/wp-admin/includes/comment.php on line 162
```

I've got no idea what this error means, though a google search turned up several websites with the same error; for example:

[Site](http://www.lead-abc.de/wp-admin/includes/comment.php)

All help appreciated!

Comment: in which file you are using this?

Answer (score 0):

Reupload fresh copies of all Wordpress files and folders, except for wp-config.php. Some of them didn't fully upload the first time.